# VSCode 'Unable to open file.cs: File Not Found'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've broken my vscode project by renaming the folder or something. Not totally sure what happened. The problem is whilst I can still build and run no problems, something has been messed up so that when I get a compilation error for example when I double click on the message it says

Unable to open 'XXXController.cs':File Not Found
(file://Controllers/XXXController.cs)

Somewhere along the line it seems to have lost the full path to the cs files for 1 of 3 projects in my source folder. I was under the impression that vscode doesn't maintain a list of files in the project so I'm at a loss to work out how I can recover other than recreating the project?

There are other issues as well - intellisense doesn't seem to work for this project either.

Does anyone have any ideas how I try and fix this?

Edit: It presents an option to create the 'missing' file. When I do so it creates a new file in C:\Controllers\ rather than in the \Controllers folder under the *.csproj location?

Regards
Dave

Comment: I assume it has a list of some kind because it tracks recently opened files and directories.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes that's true. It seems that the build error contains a relative file reference which isn't relative to what it thinks the root folder is but I cannot quite work out what's wrong

Comment: you're using a bunch of plugins. Without knowing which ones as there are several, it's tough to say. I would try disabling all of them

Comment: I've only got the C# and Docker extensions active. I'll try and recreate the project

Comment: It's potentially a bug in vscode. I recreated by "dotnet new webapi" then making the sample \Controllers\ValuesController.cs file invalid. It seems to have problems with cs files which aren't in the project root folder - it seems to assume they're relative to C:\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem appears to be that msbuild by default doesn't output full paths when it reports errors, omnisharp-vscode requires full paths to resolve files so adding GenerateFullPaths=true to the .vscode\tasks.json seems to resolve the issue.

i.e.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/Test.Api/Test.Api.csproj",
                // Ask msbuild to generate full paths for file names.
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: my tasks.json looks a little different.  I had to add the arg to the end of the `"command"` line: `"command": "dotnet build MyProject.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true",`

Comment: @GraehamF I believe the schema has changed, you're probably using a fiel with a newer or older version?