# VSCode: CMD + Click Go to Definition returns "Unable to open 'file-name': File not found" error

Tags: visual-studio-code

When trying to cmd + click through to an imported definition from another file in my local directory, an `Unable to open 'file-name': File not found` error appears. Likewise, using ctrl + cmd + click > "Go to definition" returns the same.

This appears to be related to imported .scss files, but I have not confirmed it's restricted to only that file type. It almost seems as though VSCode is rejecting imported files without a file suffix (ie `../sass/media-queries";`

I reviewed a few similar s/o threads that mentioned deleting the `~/.vscode` hidden folder (that just deleted my extensions) and changing the `GenerateFullPaths=true` setting mentioned here: [VSCode 'Unable to open file.cs: File Not Found'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826816/vscode-unable-to-open-file-cs-file-not-found).

This is with a fresh install of VSCode v1.33.1  with, currently, no extensions.